# Bulk Upload to iTunes store

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

Right now I am using third party services to upload my publishing company's epubs to iTunes (300+ in total)

I want to bypass that and upload them to iTunes myself. I already have a contract with iTunes and signed all the necessary papers.

I don't use Apple products.

From what I understand I would need iTunes Connect and/or iTunes Producer to upload my files and meta data to the store.

Is there any way to shorten that?

My self programmed Unix factory produces epub and onix metadata files.
Can't I simply bulk upload them via FTP? I don't want to manually import them into Apple environments and hence care for two different repositories with identical content.

Any push into the right direction is highly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Only possible automation is via Transporter:

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/books/faq/Transporter_Getting%20Set%20Up#65813084 (Getting Started)

https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/ (User Guide; unfortunately not really extensive)